# Characteristic function equal to $1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Is the fact that the characteristic function of $X$ is equal to $1$ enough to say that $X=0$ almost surely?

Is this the correct proof?

The characteristic function is determined uniquely. The random variable $X=0$ has the characteristic function equal to $1$. Hence $X=0$. But why only almost surely? Can anyone relate?

Comment: The distribution is unique. If $X = Y$ ae. then their distributions are the same.

Comment: I see no proof in your post. For a proof that, if $E(e^{itX})=1$ for every $t$, then $X=0$ almost surely, note that $E(e^{itX})=1$ if and only if $tX\in2\pi\mathbb Z$ almost surely. Thus, if $E(e^{itX})=E(e^{isX})=1$ for some nonzero $s$ and $t$, then $X\in(2\pi\mathbb Z/t)\cap(2\pi\mathbb Z/s)$ almost surely. Finally, if $s/t$ is irrational, then $(2\pi\mathbb Z/t)\cap(2\pi\mathbb Z/s)=\{0\}$ hence you are done.

Comment: For the  characteristic function to be $1$ then $P(X=0)=1$, but $X$ could have other values as long as the probability is $0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg you mean their probability tends to zero or is zero, when it is zero, they do not exist right?

Comment: It is $0$.  Simple example $0\le X\le 1$, where $X=x$ for rational $x$ and $X=0$ otherwise, where the probability space is the unit interval, with ordinary measure.